# Rails: has_and_belongs_to_many validation that depends on other associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

A *product* belongs to a *product_group*. A *product_group* **has_many** *features*. A *product* **has_and_belongs_to_many** *features*.

Validation: a *product* may not have a *feature* that does not belong to its *product_group*.

What's the most "Rails way" of performing this validation?

(Rails 6, Ruby 2.7)

Edit: code examples:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product_group
  has_and_belongs_to_many :features
  validate :all_features_belong_to_my_product_group

  def all_features_belong_to_my_product_group
    # what goes here? Is there a better way?
  end
end

class ProductGroup < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :features
end

class Feature < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to: ProductGroup
  has_and_belongs_to_many :products
end
```

Comment: Can you create a minimal example of the classes and their assocations instead of making those willing to answer do all the work for you?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  But from the sound of it this is not a case where you should be using `has_and_belongs_to_many ` which is extremely limited in its usefulness and you should instead use `has_many though:` that provides a join model. https://flatironschool.com/blog/why-you-dont-need-has-and-belongs-to-many

Comment: has_many :through would work but validating the product model is easy without the join model. I wondered if Rails provides a quick way of recording and displaying validation errors with these associations like it does with so many other things. PS I'm not sure how expressing the problem in plain English rather than code equates to making people "do all the work for me" but I've added it